# The .change for radio are not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a second thing in my page:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Book.HasAt)
```

Which is radio (Changed in EditorTemplates):

```
@model bool?

Yes @Html.RadioButton("", true, Model.HasValue && Model.Value == true, htmlAttributes: ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
No @Html.RadioButton("", false, Model.HasValue && Model.Value == false, htmlAttributes: ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

Also this is how it looks on page:

```
Yes <input id="Book_HasAt" name="Book.HasAt" type="radio" value="True" class="jq-radio">
No <input id="Book_HasAt" name="Book.HasAt" type="radio" value="False" class="jq-radio checked">
```

Depending on value I need to show or hide div with some data.

I have a script for it:

```
$("#Book_HasAt").change(function () {
            var status = $(this);
            if (status.is(":checked")) {
                $("#SuppSelect").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#SuppSelect").hide()
            }
        });
```

Script are working but there is a issue.
My radio have a two values, Yes No (true and false). By default it is false. For some reason **script are working ONLY when I change false to true**. When I am reverting it back from true to false, script are not reacting at all and as a result div are not hidding anymore. Thi is unacceptable for me.

How can I fix this and where the problem could be?

Comment: Can you add the HTML to the question?

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle out of this showing the wrong behaviour.

Comment: radio button only fire change event on check, not when 'unchecked' by clicking other radion button from same group (name attribute) so anyway your logic checking for checked or not cannot work properly. Maybe you are just looking for `checkbox` instead

Comment: em... A. Wolff, didn't got wha you actually mean (my English is bad, probably because of it). If I click to false, it will be checked and true will be unchecked. Doesn' this meen that check  for false should trigger change event? And no, I'm not looking for checkbox

Comment: @OlegsJasjko I meant that: http://jsfiddle.net/g4xkzpdp/  Because IDs anyway ***must*** be unique on document context. Now you'd have better to provide online sample which replicates your issue, to make it clearer. Now i'm not an ASP guy, maybe `#Book_HasAt` is referring to a container, in this case, using `$(this)` in change handler doesn't make sense...

Comment: Well, actually your example has replicated it enought. The only difference is that I have div instead of alerd, but the issue is the same. So.. is there a way to... deal with whis thing?

Comment: The only way to uncheck a radio is by clicking other radio from same group, so set your logic according to bind change event on all RADIOs from same group. If you uncheck a radio programatically, then you can still trigger manually the onchange event. Again, providing a concrete sample of your issue would help better because actually your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: em... As I told already, yourexample done the thing better that my bad explanation (I added in my question how my inputs looks like). How exactly can I bind this action? I mean, is it simplt new @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Book.HasAt, new {onchange="SomeAction()"}) and function  for it?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko BUT how do you switch this radio button to unchecked once it has been checked??? That's all the question in fact. Now if you are using duplicate IDs, meaning more than one radio with id `Book_HasAt`, this is not valid anyway. See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t118zhzz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Classess instead of IDs.. id is unique .. and jquery just take action with the first element with this Id

use

```
'input[name="Book.HasAt"]'
```

instead of

```
"#Book_HasAt"
```

Comment: I cant use jq-radio just because it is used for every radio I have, and @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Book.HasAt) is only one of them

Comment: Oooops, now I see where my error was when I tried it before! I lost "" in name=. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change id into class

```
$(".jq-radio").change(function () {
            var status = $(this);
            if (status.val()=="True") {
                $("#SuppSelect").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#SuppSelect").hide()
            }
        });
```

you can use this...

Comment: I added input example to my question and... how can I add class to already existing class?

Comment: Well, in answer below  already told it: "I cant use jq-radio just because it is used for every radio I have, and @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Book.HasAt) is only one of them"